# Install Surface Kernel on Try Ubuntu USB

Tags: boot, kernel, live-usb, surface

I want to install Ubuntu on my Surface Pro 4, but I'm concerned. I've created a bootable USB with Ubuntu 21.10 and can successfully boot and explore the OS. It looks really good...BUT some of the features don't work. The good news is that after going through other posts ,is that the alternate Surface-kernel appears to resolve the issues I was experiencing (touch screen for example). I would like to explore this just a bit more using the OS from the USB before I actually install it. The leads me to the specific question. Can I install the surface-kernel on the USB so I can use the "try" mode (live-usb)?
I've seen other posts saying you could select (from the boot manager) alternate kernels such as the surface kernel, but I don't see this option after trying them all; so I hoping I can update the USB. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot update the USB image. It is read-only.

There are instructions for experts on how to take a running system and compress it and convert into that kind of USB image, but it's a complex task that is fraught with pitfalls for a beginner.